# xsl - how to grab multiple same name nested elements?

Tags: xml, xslt

Would anyone know what i am missing here? I have a export that for example, is broken up by the code element. I am trying to display each site element that falls under the SiteDataSet. Sometimes there is only 1 site while sometimes they are 3 or more.

here is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<export>
    <run-date>03/20/2017
        <code>items
            <type>Job
                <number>9999999990-01</number>
                <SiteDataSet>
                    <Site>Accounting</Site>
                    <Site>Energy</Site>
                </SiteDataSet>
                <content><![CDATA[]]></content>
            </type>
        </code>
        <code>items2
            <type>Job
                <number>9999999910-01</number>
                <SiteDataSet>
                    <Site>Finance</Site>
                    <Site>Energy</Site>
                    <Site>Driving</Site>
                </SiteDataSet>
                <content><![CDATA[]]></content>
            </type>
        </code>
    </run-date>
</export>
```

here is the xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/> 

        <xsl:template match="/*/*">
                <xsl:element name="Posting">
                        <xsl:for-each select="code/type">
                                <xsl:element name="Job">
                                        <xsl:element name="Number"><xsl:value-of select="translate(./*[local-name()='number'],'-','')"/></xsl:element>
                                        <xsl:element name="Sites"/>
                                </xsl:element>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:element>
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is the output xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Posting>
       <Job>
          <Number>999999999001</Number>
          <Sites/>
       </Job>
       <Job>
          <Number>999999991001</Number>
          <Sites/>
       </Job>
    </Posting>
```

Comment: Your XML is not well-formed, as you are missing a closing `</run_date>` tag. Also, your XSLT seems to be missing some lines. A number of the `<xsl:element>` tags are not closed, neither is the `<xsl:for-each>`. Can you correct these in your question, please? Also, can you show your expected output? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i got it working so this can be closed.

```
<xsl:element name="Sites">
    <xsl:for-each select="SiteDataSet/Site">
        <Site><xsl:value-of select="."/></Site>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:element>
```